# React Native image-picker error when building for ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After executing this command

npx react-native run-ios -- --reset-cache

I get the following error
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/gabriel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wooapp-ecvnzpvdhxltnxeoglpliezckkzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-image-picker.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImagePickerManager.o /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/wiii/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/ios/ImagePickerManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

It seems related to the image picker library butI dont know how to fix it...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should downgrade your react-native-image-picker version.
In my case, when the react-native-image-picker version was 7.0.2(latest version), I encountered the compile err like you.
But after the react-native-image-picker version was downgraded to 4.0.6, the err was resolved.